# Use an older generator-angular-fullstack version

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, generator, yeoman

I want to generate a project with generator-angular-fullstack, but I don't want to use ECMAScript 6. Do you know how I can downgrade the generator? or do you have a better solution for generating a project with angular node and mysql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit weird that we have to downgrade just to be able to using javascript and CSS by default, not only choose between typescript, babel and various :) Check the current version :

```bash
npm list -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

you will probably see something like

```
/home/<user>/npm/lib
└── generator-angular-fullstack@3.1.1
```

Check if you have another local version installed (very likely if you not have been strictly [globally](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) from scratch) `list` without `-g` :

```
npm list generator-angular-fullstack
/some/other/dir
└── generator-angular-fullstack@3.3.0
```

Now, if you have a local version as shown above, uninstall it

```bash
npm uninstall generator-angular-fullstack
```

Finally install the [release](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/releases) of generator-angular-fullstack you want. My prefered versions for javascript, HTML, CSS, mongodb, express etc is `2.0.13` and `2.1.1`

```
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack@2.1.1
```

check version again to see if you actually have switched releases :

```bash
npm list -g generator-angular-fullstack
```

should now show

```
/home/<user>/npm/lib
└── generator-angular-fullstack@2.1.1
```

go to your working directory and run the generator

```bash
yo angular-fullstack
```

..release `2.1.1` is executed. NB: If you now and then see some `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bower@>=1.0.0` etc, ignore it! It has not so much to do with the generator itself, and everything works fine - so dont worry about that.